# How to access any element in a 2D array in C using pointer?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

I want to access an element in a 2D array in C using pointer

for example (this using traditional way)

```
multi[0][1] = ....
```

I tried this way

```
*(*(multi+0)+1) = ....
```

But it gives me an error saying

```
" pointer required "
```

So what am i suppose to do?

Actually this is what I was doing

```
void state_array(int *pointer , int *multi){
   int i ;
   for ( i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++){
   *(*(multi + i) + 0 )= *(pointer+i) ;
                                }
     for ( i = 4 ; i < 8 ; i++){
   *(*(multi + i ) + 1 )= *(pointer+i) ;
                                }
    for ( i = 8 ; i < 12 ; i++){
   *(*(multi + i ) + 2 )= *(pointer+i) ;
                                }
   for ( i = 12 ; i < 16 ; i++){
   *(*(multi + i ) + 3 )= *(pointer+i) ;
                                }
                                  }
```

Comment: When you post something like `it gives me an error`, expect down votes to ensue.

Comment: To clarify; you should really post the *exact error message* when you're asking a question about an error message.

Comment: what is the datatype of your variable `multi`? is it an `int` 2D array?

Comment: I can't understand the code. What's the main aim of the code?

Comment: `multi` is a pointer, `*(multi+i)` adds an offset to the pointer and then dereferences it. The result is an `int` not a pointer. You then add a value to this `int` and try to dereference the result which explains the error message.

Comment: @UsamaElRakhawey Please specify the function calling code. What are all the values you are passing to the function?

Answer (score 1):

There is **no problem with *(*(multi+0)+1).** It will work. Please specify full code to find out the error.

[Refer the link](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ab/15-123S09/lectures/Lecture%2006%20-%20%20Pointer%20to%20a%20pointer.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

The reason that you get that particular error message is that the variable `multi` is type `int *`, and not `int **`.  Your function treats it as an `int **` by dereferencing it twice in `*(*(multi + i ) + j)`

Break the expression down:

1. `*(multi + i)` dereferences the pointer `multi+i`.  Because `multi` is type `int *`, this is fine.  The resulting type is `int`.
2. `*( ... + j)` attempts to dereference `... + j`.  The problem is that `...` is type `int`, and `... + j` is type `int`.  Your cannot dereference an `int` (it's an integral type, not a pointer).

Two solutions:

1. Declare `multi` to be type `int **`, and pass in an actual `int **`
2. Keep `multi` as an `int *` and use single-index addressing

Solution 1 only works if you allocate an array of `int *` and then fill it to point to arrays of `int`.  It **will not** work if you declare a multidimensional array in C (i.e., `int myarray[23][78]`).  In C, a declared multidimensional array is kept in contiguous memory, and this information is lost if you pass it to a function as a pointer-to-a-pointer.

The second solution is to choose either row-major or column-major indexing, and the pass in the relevant sizes.  You should probably be doing this anyway.  If you choose row-major indexing (rows are contiguous in memory), an M x N matrix `multi` is addressed as

```
multi[i + M*j]
```

If you choose column-major indexing (columns are contiguous in memory), the same matrix is addressed as

```
multi[N*i + j]
```

This solution **will** work for statically-declared multidimensional arrays in C, and allows you to dynamically allocate a multidimensional array in C with minimal overhead.

Also, be aware that statically-declared multidimensional arrays in C uses column-major indexing when they're accessed as `mat[i][j]`.  However, if you're doing serious matrix work, there are good reasons to prefer row-major indexing.  Finally, Fortran uses row-major indexing, and if your code needs to interface with Fortran (as numerical code often does), you should probably prefer row-major indexing.